# Last reputation changes clarification

Tags: support, bug, reputation

SO,

I have a question about list of "last reputation changes" that I can see in profile of user. As a sample, my SO's [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2637490/alma-do) has some mismatches that I want to understand.

Here's current main tab for profile:

[image]

As you can see, it's `8` in score of answers, sorted by votes, but only `+60` in last *reputation changes* tab. However, if I'll go to [`"view more"`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2637490/alma-do?tab=reputation) I'll see:

[image]

-i.e. quite as expected, `+80` (and answer that I'm talking about is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874892/is-it-possible-to-select-a-random-column-in-one-row/21875640#21875640) - and currently it has `8` score)

So what is it? Am I understanding last reputation changes tab incorrectly or may be it's a bug?

Comment: Looks like it's cutting off at the event that took place at 10:33UTC. You have two upvotes that are older than that, which matches what you're seeing. But no one really knows exactly how that summary thing works.

Comment: Well, I suppose _someone_ knows that :p Thanks for your though - indeed, it may be restricted by some daily timeline (but then strange then in left column it's working well)

Comment: @animuson including us